# Viewing \n and \r characters in Vim?

Tags: vim, end-of-line

Is there a way to make \n or \r characters visible in vim?  (I want to be able to see if the csv file I am looking at uses just \n or \r and \n at the end of lines.

Comment: :set invlist seems to do the trick, but is the $ an \n or a \r\n?

Comment: Vim usually remarks on this when you load the file, doesn't it? (eg, will say [DOS] with the file name if the line endings are `\r\n`).

Comment: I opened a file that I wrote in Windows and another that I wrote in Ubuntu with Vim, and used :set invlist on both of them.  I expect that the end of line characters are different for both files, but Vim flagged them up as $ in both.  So I think you want a different command.  Don't know what it is, though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:setl fileformat?
```

`dos` means CR-LF (consistently; if only some lines contain both, it'll be listed as `unix`, and you'll see `^M` characters at the end of those lines), `unix` means LF; `mac` means only CR newlines.

Comment: hmm when I ran that command it said `fileformat=dos` so that must mean CR followed by LF (\r\n) ?

Comment: @leeand00: Correct. If you deal with different fileformats regularly, it may make sense to add `%{&l:fileformat}` to a custom `statusline`.